# What firmware version is my OCZ Vertex SSD?

Tags: ssd, upgrade, firmware

I have an OCZ Vertex series I (SATA II) SSD that is starting to fail. I would like to try upgrading the firmware, but don't know what version is currently on it. How can I find out?

According to [their download site](http://www.ocztechnology.com/ssd_tools/OCZ_Vertex,_Agility,_Vertex_Turbo,_Vertex_EX,_Solid_2/) the latest is 1.7. I've tried launching the flash utility for that, but it doesn't get past `- InitDisk`, when I boot it of my USB key. Where can I download older versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Firmware Upgrade Manual](http://www.ocztechnology.com/resources/drivers/Vertex_Firmware_Flashing_Guide.pdf) you should be able to check the firmware version of the drive in Device Manager.  Presumably the device name will reflect the firmware version.

If not try going to the `Details` tab for the device in Device Manager and select `Hardware Ids` in the `Properties` dropdown you may see an extra bit of information in the drive name which may show what the firmware version.

-=EDIT=-

As a rather amusing aside, I can see why your firmware update is failing, as on their [download page](http://www.ocztechnology.com/ssd_tools/OCZ_Vertex,_Agility,_Vertex_Turbo,_Vertex_EX,_Solid_2/):

> *CURRENT FIRMWARE RELEASE is v1.7
>
> Note:  Current FW must be v1.6 before flashing to v1.7
> Please backup all data on the SSD as a precaution

I cannot immediately see V1.6, so it's rather stupid that they do not post previous versions of the firmware if it requires an incremental update.

Are you sure you don't have a Vertex 2 or Vertex LE whose [firmware is at V1.35](http://www.ocztechnology.com/ssd_tools/OCZ_Vertex_2,_Vertex_LE,_Agility_2/)?

Comment: Thanks, seems like it's 1.3. You didn't find old upgrades by any chance?

Comment: @Znarkus have a look at http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?252-Downloads-for-all-OCZ-SSD-s-%28Read-Only%29